# mod_rewrite to redirect to same named folder on different server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have a company that I'm working with who want to run 2 different servers from same domain - one Apache, and one Windows 2008 - this is to deal with some php backend content, and some legacy asp.net material.  The Apache box will be the main server for the site, with the windows box to serve some peripheral forums, and microsites.

Was wondering about the possibility of creating a mod_rewrite on the Apache box to redirect to certain content on the windows server - for example:

http://mydomain.com/mywindowsfolder - content needs to come from windows server

So - rewrite rule in place within httpd.conf as follows:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mywindowsfolder/
RewriteRule ^/$ http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/mywindowsfolder/ [P,L]

*(IP address of windows box to be used)*

I was reading about the P flag in mod_rewrite - would this work so that the url remained as http://mydomain.com/mywindowsfolder?  - and if so, please could someone help with a correct regular expression - i wasn't sure if the above might create an infinite loop.

It would be important to not display the IP address of the windows box.

I'm guessing the alternative is to use sub domains with DNS and the Address Records - would that be a more advisable route to take?

Thank you for any advice,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to use [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

```
ProxyPass /mywindowsfolder/ http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/mywindowsfolder/
```

The drawback is, you cannot use it in a .htaccess file, but only in the main config file or in a virtual host context.